# Debugger not hitting to the Break point

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm working with two separate applications where redirects from one app to another. 1st app(MVC app) running with "start without debugging" 2nd app(ASP app) I'm running with debigging(direct f5).  It was unable to hit break point to my both apps. Showing a "A break point will not currently hit. the source code is different from original version". How to make my break point to be hit ?

Comment: Are you running in release configuration instead of debug?

Comment: Also, try just rebuilding all (ctrl+K, ctrl+B) and trying again.

Comment: Clean and rebuild the whole solution. This may work.

Comment: release configuration mean ?

Comment: Rebuild done lot of times.

Comment: Clean also done a lot..

Comment: On your menu bar there is a dropdown that will have in it "Debug" and "Release"

Comment: Sorry, I'm running with "Debug" mode itself.

Comment: In Tools->Options->Debugging->General, uncheck "Require source files to exactly match the original version". This should make the "Source code is different" error go away.

Comment: @Georg Patscheider Really thank a lot. It solved my problem. Hope it wont get back again. Let me check for some time.

Comment: @Georg Patscheider, It shows back again. Even though "Require source files to exactly match the original version" it was unchecked.